# Python: gcd code is not printed

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor

I wrote a code to calculate greatest common denominator of a user inputted number.

But I don't know why this code is not printing the result.
I think, Maybe  the reason is while loop takes too much time to calculate.

If I enter first number = 4 and second number = 6, the result is not printed.

But if I enter fist number = 12 and second number = 24, the result is printed '12'.

What is the better way to fix this code?

```
num1 = int(input("Enter the fist number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

def gcd(num1, num2):
    i = min(num1, num2)
    while True:
        if (num1 % i == 0) and (num2 % i == 0):
            return i
        i - 1

print("The greatest common denominator of both number is", gcd(num1, num2))
```

Comment: For one thing' `i - 1` doesn't change `i`.... try `i -= 1`

Answer (score 0):

the notation you used to decrease i doesn't exist in python, it should be changed to:

```
i=i-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of i. Just use `i=i-1` instead of just i-1.

This is why when your number doesn't divide the greater number in the first iteration it goes into infinite loop since you are not changing the value of a i.